# I baked you a pie!

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

There is an asdfmovie video about a pie flavoured pie. Someone also made an edited version with more pies, so I created this challenge.

The input is a positive integer.

The code should first output the following string:

```
I baked you a pie!
Oh boy, what flavour?
```

Then, the next line should be `PIE`  (input number of times) + `flavour.`.

Next, print a blank line.

After that, ASCII-art pies should be drawn.

Here is what a size-1 pie looks like.

```
 _________
/         \
-----------
 \       /
  -------
```

Size-2 pie:

```
 _____________
/             \
---------------
 \           /
  -----------
```

Size-3 pie:

```
 _________________
/                 \
-------------------
 \               /
  ---------------
```

Each pie starting from size-2 should be four characters longer on each line than the pie one smaller.

The program should draw (input number + 1) pies, seperated by newlines, with increasing sizes (1 at the top, 2 directly below it, etc).

The pies should be centred.

Examples:

Input 1

```
I baked you a pie!
Oh boy, what flavour?
PIE flavour.

   _________
  /         \
  -----------
   \       /
    -------
 _____________
/             \
---------------
 \           /
  -----------
```

Input 2

```
I baked you a pie!
Oh boy, what flavour?
PIE PIE flavour.

     _________
    /         \
    -----------
     \       /
      -------
   _____________
  /             \
  ---------------
   \           /
    -----------
 _________________
/                 \
-------------------
 \               /
  ---------------
```

Input 3

```
I baked you a pie!
Oh boy, what flavour?
PIE PIE PIE flavour.

       _________
      /         \
      -----------
       \       /
        -------
     _____________
    /             \
    ---------------
     \           /
      -----------
   _________________
  /                 \
  -------------------
   \               /
    ---------------
 _____________________
/                     \
-----------------------
 \                   /
  -------------------
```

This is code-golf, so use any language, shortest code wins.

Comment: "Dad I'm hungry" "hi hungry I'm dad" "why did you name this way? Why why why?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 126 bytes<sup>UTF-8</sup> (87<sup>*†*</sup>) [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage))

```
Ý·ε5+'_×1ú'/'-6y+×D„ \s¨¨2ú).B.º}˜.c…PIEIиðý.•FóG ñ•ÁDŠ“I baked€î€…Èš!
Ohíå,€Àÿ?
ÿÿ.

ÿ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8NxD2021z21Vjz883fDwLnV9dd1Ku8PTXR41zFOIKT604tAKo8O7NPWc9A7tqj09Ry/5UcOyAE9Xzws7Dm84vFdJIS0nsSy/tEjJ5eiCRw1zPBWSErNTUx41rTm8DkgA1R7uOLpQkcs/4/Daw0t1QOINh/fbcx3ef3i/HheQ@v/fGAA)

*†: Could be **86 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)** by using `.•FóG ñ•Á` instead of `" flavour"`, but the longer one is cheaper in UTF-8 encoding..* 
[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8NxD2021z21Vjz883fDwLnV9dd1Ku8PTXR41zFOIKT604tAKo8O7NPWc9A7tqj09Ry/5UcOyAE9Xzws7Dm84vFfvUcMit8Ob3RUObwSyDje6HF3wqGGOp0JSYnZqyqOmNYfXAQmgjsMdRxcqcvlnHF57eKkOSLzh8H57rsP7D@/X4wJS//8bAwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
Ý                # Push a list in the range [0, (implicit) input]
 ·               # Double each value in this list
  5+             # Then add 5 to each value
    ε            # Map over each 2v+5 value `y`:
     '_×        '#  Push a string of that many "_"
        1ú       #  Prepend a leading space
     '/         '#  Push "/"
     '-y>×      '#  Push a string with y+1 (2v+6) amount of "-"
     D           #  Duplicate it
     „ \         #  Push string " \"
     s           #  Swap so the duplicated "-"-string is at the top again
      ¨¨         #  Remove two "--" (2v+4 amount of "-")
        2ú       #  And pad two leading spaces instead
          )      #  Wrap all five strings into a list
           .B    #  Add trailing spaces to make all strings the same length
             .º  #  Mirror each line with overlap
  }˜             # After the map: flatten the list of lists of lines
    .c           # Add leading spaces to centralize all lines,
                 # and join all lines with newline delimiter
…PIE             # Push string "PIE"
    Iи           # Repeat it the input amount of times as list
      ðý         # Join it with space delimiter
.•FóG ñ•         # Push compressed string "flavour "
        Á        # Rotate it to " flavour"
         D       # Duplicate it
          Š      # Tripleswap the top three values on the stack
“I baked€î€…Èš!  # Push dictionary string "I baked you a pie!
Ohíå,€Àÿ?        # Oh boy, what pie?
ÿÿ.              # ÿÿ.
                 # 
ÿ                # ÿ",
                 # where the ÿ are one by one filled with the strings on the stack
                 # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to use the dictionary?* and *How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `.•FóG ñ•` is `"flavour "` and `“I baked€î€…Èš!\nOhíå,€Àÿ?\nÿÿ.\n\nÿ` is `"I baked you a pie!\nOh boy, what pie?\nÿÿ.\n\nÿ"`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-M5.10.0 -na`, 169 bytes

```perl
say"I baked you a pie!
Oh boy, what flavour?
","PIE "x$_,"flavour.
",map{$i="  "x("@F"-$_)," __",_ x($#a=7+4*$_),"
$i/ @a \\
$i----",$j="-"x$#a,"
$i \\@a/
$i  $j
"}0..$_
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoic2F5XCJJIGJha2VkIHlvdSBhIHBpZSFcbk9oIGJveSwgd2hhdCBmbGF2b3VyP1xuXCIsXCJQSUUgXCJ4JF8sXCJmbGF2b3VyLlxuXCIsbWFweyRpPVwiICBcIngoXCJARlwiLSRfKSxcIiBfX1wiLF8geCgkI2E9Nys0KiRfKSxcIlxuJGkvIEBhIFxcXFxcbiRpLS0tLVwiLCRqPVwiLVwieCQjYSxcIlxuJGkgXFxcXEBhL1xuJGkgICRqXG5cIn0wLi4kXyIsImFyZ3MiOiItTTUuMTAuMFxuLW5hIiwiaW5wdXQiOiIxXG4yXG4zXG4xMiJ9)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 176 bytes

Builds the output recursively, from bottom to top.

```javascript
f=(n,p,s=`I baked you a pie!
Oh boy, what flavour?
`)=>~n?f(n-1,-~p,s+=n?"PIE ":`flavour.
`)+`
 _2_
/ 0 \\
--1--
 \\0/
  1`.replace(/^|\d/gm,i=>" -_"[+i].repeat(i?7+n*4:p*2)):s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtBC4IwGEDv@xVfnrbcNCsIhOmpQ6e6Z7mlM1e2DbUiiP66GXR78N67yIfsila7nhlbqmGoODbU0Y6LDZzkVZXwsneQ4LSaoG0NJ/ui8KxlD1UjH/bepkgQnnxMWmHDIso@4@xzk3q7zRq8WPyzYMx8gSCf5yiEGWQZYixiDI00CxFAJIJWuUYWCofHd1aG5xvVPPGA5d7e14efVbLHOl35ZrqM3XROSNwNhTWdbVTQ2DOu8IKQ4Qs)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (                       // f is a recursive function taking:
  n,                        //   n = input
  p,                        //   p = left-padding counter
  s =                       //   s = header string
  `I baked you a pie!\n` +  //
  `Oh boy, what flavour?\n` //
) =>                        //
~n ?                        // if n is greater than -1:
  f(                        //   do a recursive call:
    n - 1,                  //     decrement n
    -~p,                    //     increment p
    s += n ? "PIE "         //     append "PIE " to s if n != 0
           : `flavour.\n`   //     or the final part otherwise
  ) + (                     //   end of recursive call
    `\n` +                  //  \   
    ` _2_\n` +              //   |  this is our pie template
    `/ 0 \\\n` +            //   |_ where digits 0, 1 and 2
    `--1--\n` +             //   |  are used as placeholders
    ` \\0/\n` +             //   |  for repeated characters
    `  1`                   //  /
  ).replace(                //   replace in the template:
    /^|\d/gm,               //   each beginning of line and
    i =>                    //   each digit with:
    " -_"[+i]               //     one of these characters
    .repeat(                //     repeated:
      i ?                   //       if this is a digit:
        7 + n * 4           //         7n + 4 times
      :                     //       else (left padding):
        p * 2               //         2p times
    )                       //     end of repeat()
  )                         //   end of replace()
:                           // else:
  s                         //   return the header string
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 88 characters, 140 bytes

```
ＮθI baked you a pie!¶Oh boy, what flavour?¶×PIE θflavour.Ｄ⎚ＤＦ⁺⁵⊗…⁰⊕θ«←×_ι↓ /Ｐ⊕ι↘-\⊖ι↙»‖Ｂ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iOSOxKDk_MWfBgqWlJWm6Fjd73u9Zd26Hp0JSYnZqikJlfqlCokJBZqrioW3-GQpJ-ZU6CuUZiSUKaTmJZfmlRfaHth2eHuDpqnBuB1RE7_2eJY_6ZgHJ93uWPWrc9ahx66Ou6Y8agOwNj7qmnttxaPWjtgmHp8ef2_mobbKC_vs9YGEgZ4ZuzKOuaSDWzEO7HzVMe79nEcRNUKetiFbS1c0rUYpdaAwRAAA) Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the number of PIEs.

```
I baked you a pie!¶Oh boy, what flavour?¶×PIE θflavour.Ｄ⎚
```

Output the desired text.

```
Ｄ
```

Output an extra blank line.

```
Ｆ⁺⁵⊗…⁰⊕θ
```

Loop over the half pie widths.

```
«←×_ι↓ /Ｐ⊕ι↘-\⊖ι↙»
```

Draw the left half of a pie to the canvas.

```
‖Ｂ
```

Reflect to complete the pies.

Would be 83 SBCS bytes using string compression:

```
Ｎθ”(KＲC¿~8◨±⦄⊕⁰↙]V⊕ＡＣＹ>|⊙Ｃ↙∕›…<·ＤÞ↖pÞ”×PIE θflavour.Ｄ⎚ＤＦ⁺⁵⊗…⁰⊕θ«←×_ι↓ /Ｐ⊕ι↘-\⊖ι↙»‖Ｂ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZDBSsQwFEVxOfMVz6wykKogguhC0LooOFqKOyuSdl6nxTTppEmHIn6JmxFGcOf_-DWmtjqDZhO4991zX_LynuZcp4qL1erNmsw7_tzJA1lZc23LBDVdTE7HoS6koSSAhD_iDFplgUNV4G4sb3JIVMtgmXMDmeCNsvosluQ3dVuUWFMSBpdAGCwmG9wwvdfN-rasqLsvBHJNt4RMaaChsDU9YuArmwic0YjLOdIDBoFMNZYojRMd2h14Go96_skVZobB0P_gyouu_Mf11VIyILDf1Y-mVpii-na2mf8SUTHPHZR4cUw2lo9_I1PVYJ_otnDK8zjCTGBqzq0xqDPRutet6ySth2__uCNeI0jH9qQh96-Hvf4F) Link is to verbose version of code.